# Wait till API response before changing view with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Working on a car dealership site and playing with `vue router`.

The **issue** currently is that I have a homepage with a grid of vehicle, **when clicking to view one on its own page I have to wait for the random parts to load in ,which causes page height jumps** etc.

Is there a way I can trigger the view to load a method but only change the route and view when I say to (api has returned a response)?

On YouTube for example, you click a link and get the progress bar before the view changes.

Thanks.

Comment: The piece of documentation you want [is listed here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your page height jump could be resolved by [this](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html).

As for pre-loading the data, you can use the `beforeRouteEnter()` function, [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html).